# Can't delete boot options

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios, fedora, asus-laptop

Boot option #1 in BIOS is Windows Boot Manager.

Boot option #2 in BIOS is Ubuntu and #3 is Fedora 35.

I'm using Asus Vivobook 15 X510Q with 4GB RAM bought in India.

I had two Linux distros earlier and they have been deleted already but boot options are still there. I tried disabling and deleting boot option #2 and #3 but after saving changes and checking BIOS they just magically reappear in boot options.

I tried using EasyBCD and now can't boot Windows 10.

I have Ubuntu 21.10 live on an SD card but it's not shown in boot override.

I want to delete boot option #2 and #3 and have a dual-boot setup with windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Sorry for any typos, I'm just too frustrated

Comment: You can **and should** [edit] the question to improve readability. Please correct the typos, use proper sentences and paragraphs.

Comment: For UEFI systems you can use **EasyUEFI**, never EasyBCD which only works for BIOS/Legacy. And yes, EasyUEFI can delete .efi files/entries that you no longer need.

Comment: I now have no access to windows as it is now asking me for a live disk  while booting as I pointed out in the question and EasyBCD has its damage (my mistake) what to do now, my Ubuntu live sd card is also not shown in boot override what should I do?

Comment: And someone has also given this question -1 already IDK why!? My first question on Superuser

Comment: You should have a Windows installation USB media available, if not make one from a different computer preferably using the official Media Creation Tool that is automatically triggered when downloading the Windows ISO from a Windows OS.

Comment: Re: the downvote please read again my first comment. You don't say sorry for typos, you edit the question to correct them. So, please start here https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and then keep in mind you're the one asking for help therefore it should be your "job" to be as clear and assertive as possible. As soon as you recognize you made mistakes in the question you correct them, you don't post a "sorry" comment. So, please [edit] the question accordingly, then ping me in a comment started with @ChanganAuto so I get a notification and then I'll gladly revert the downvote.

Comment: I don't have any other computer  so first I'll have to go buy a USB stick preferably with good storage and create windows Live disk first and then repair windows and use EasyUEFI to remove boot option #2 and #3 and setup dual boot, right?

Comment: Alternatively you can download the ISO in Ubuntu and then MKUSB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive PS - There's no "Windows live disk" in the same sense that most modern Linux distro use that term. It's always an installation media but it can also be used for repairs.

Comment: And, of course, you can always use `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu to manage boot entries but, of course, that will NOT fix your Windows. You need Windows media for that.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I have written this question with best of my knowledge and I was saying sorry because I felt like there might be a typo

Comment: ChanganAuto, I have an Ubuntu 20.10 live on a SD card but it's not shown on boot override section. If I could just boot to Ubuntu 20.10 I could've made live repair for windows
My little sister uses Windows so can't remove it completely

Comment: I haven't spotted any glaring typos but instead no proper sentences, paragraphs, nothing... Just a wall of text that is hard to read. Please correct that instead of making even more excuses. Again, you're the one asking for help so... Help others help you, as they say.

Comment: No, **you can't fix an unbootable Windows nor check for and correct eventual file system errors in NTFS partitions form Ubuntu**. And 20.10 is EoL, out of support, anyway. When installing multiple OSes you MUST have installation/live media for all of them. Problem happen all the time and you must have the tools *before* they happen or, at the very least, have the means to make them after the fact. End of story.

Comment: I've made some corrections in question  

Comment: I use my SD card reader or adaptor but both are not showing on boot override. I know problems occur but why isn't this live disk of Ubuntu not showing up!?

Comment: Honestly not enough corrections but I edited it for you. Please accept the edit, notice the downvote reversal and you're welcome.

Comment: I decided to go with Ubuntu 20.10 is because I wanted to use  latest Gnome

Comment: Now, in the vast majority of the desktop systems the SD reader ISN'T a bootable device. Linux distros can still be installed in those (not always) but the ESP - EFI System Partition - must reside elsewhere, typically in the first internal drive. So, root and everything else on the SD but then one must select the internal drive's EFI partition. But all of this is a moot point because you need to fix Windows first and that can't be done from Linux even if you manage to boot some live session.

Comment: *I decided to go with Ubuntu 20.10 is because I wanted touse latest Gnome* The lates Gnome is in the current 21.10. Ubuntu 20.10 is out of support, forget it.

Comment: Thanks. Your are so helpful and I have previously used same SD adaptor to install Fedora and Ubuntu on the same system. BTW, I'll accept your edit.

Comment: It's night here in India so I'll go and buy an USB stick tomorrow morning and repair the window using installation media and then remove boot option #2 and #3 and setup the dual boot

Comment: I mean 21.10 not 20.10 (my mistake again) 